# Sequelizer : JSONB postgres query not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to get the records on the basis of some key that are in jsonb, i am using sequelizer as ORM and postgres as a DB .  I am getting empty array of leads unexpected ...

```
 whereArr.push(db.where(
    db.cast("dataJson.basicInfo.firstName.value", 'text'),
    { [Op.iLike] : "%k%" }
));

searchBy = {
    where: {
        ...whereArr
    }
};

let leads = await Lead.findAndCountAll({
    ...searchBy,
    ...orderBy,
    ...paginate
});
```

The code work fine if i am using the column  name other than jsonb's column . 
I am unable to figure out the issue. please guide how can i achieve  that .
Thank You

Comment: testable code would be better than rumours of code,